# Java heap space error inspite of modifying eclipse.ini

Tags: java, android

I am writing an android application wherein I am using Showcaseview library. I have imported the library & the associated jar files. I get the error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I have tried increasing the values for --launcher.XXMaxPermSize - 1024m
Xms512m
-Xmx512m

I have also tried giving it even more values.
Also I tried to import jar files in a user-defined library & imported that library as one of the posts said.

But the problem still persists. Please Help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the following line in your AndroidMinifest file in your application tag

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Hope this works.